# How to convert heic to jpg in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios11, xcode9, file-format

iOS 11 has introduced new image format called HEIC. So when I upload images to server, it will be failed. So I need to convert HEIC file format to JPEG.

I tried just changing the file format, but it won't be working. So if anyone find a solution to convert HEIC file to JPEG, please provide a solution.

Answer (score 6):

There's a workaround to convert HEIC photos to JPEG before uploading them to the server :

```
NSData *jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7);
```

If you use **PHAsset**, the, in order to have the image object, you'll need to call this method from **PHImageManager**:

```
- (PHImageRequestID)requestImageForAsset:(PHAsset *)asset targetSize:(CGSize)targetSize contentMode:(PHImageContentMode)contentMode options:(nullable PHImageRequestOptions *)options resultHandler:(void (^)(UIImage *__nullable result, NSDictionary *__nullable info))resultHandler;
```

On server side you also have the ability to use [this API](https://cloudconvert.com/api/convert/heic-to-jpg)
I've created a [minimalist website](https://heictojpg.site) to handle the conversion using tifig lib.

Comment: if you would update to version 0.2.0 of tifig your website would also preserve the metadata ;)